# Assign variable to Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

Using Net 4.5.1

Have the following class Respondent:

```
namespace Whatever {
  public class Respondent {
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }

    public static Expression<Func<Respondent, bool>> compareXY(int value) {
      return x => ((x.x * 100) + x.y) > value;
    }
  }
}
```

Lets say I want to pass the body of the lamdba around.  Getting it by:

```
... some function ...
Type MemberType = typeof(<this class>).Assembly.GetType("Whatever.Respondent");

object[] parameters = new object[] { <populate with integer value> };

var expr = MemberType
  .GetMethod(MemberFunctionName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
  .Invoke(null, parameters) as LambdaExpression;

return expr.body
```

Problem is that the variable **x** (i.e. Respondent) is not defined.  For example, the functional expression **compareXY** might be included in a larger expression tree that derives from a series of predicates (i.e. standing for comparisons, literals, functions, etc):

```
...function returning Expression<Func<Respondent, bool>>...
Expr together = Predicates.Aggregate(
  (prev, next) => new And { Operands = new Expr[] { prev, next}  }
);

Expression composition = together.getExpression(context);  <-- here resolving compareXY
return Expression.Lambda(composition, new ParameterExpression[] { context });
```

Basically, the body of the lambda returned from **compareXY** has to have a variable/parameter **x** set to the **Respondent** type.

**EDIT**, Getting the following error:

```
 {"variable 'x' of type 'Charting.Models.Respondent' referenced from scope '', 
 but it is not defined"}
```

Question is how to define the variable **x** to the body of the Lambda?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @svick, When you drop the **Respondent.compareXY** expression in a Where clause (i.e. like ctx.Respondents.Where(Respondent.compareXY(4)).Count()) the **x** variable is resolved (bound somehow) to Respondent in the query.  What I want to do is the same thing but with the body of the lambda somewhere else in a bigger expression tree.

Comment: You're trying to create a function that accepts a context when the body of that function assumes that it's accepting a `Respondent`.  You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure there's a question in there, but I think you answered it:

The body of the `LambdaExpression` doesn't include the parameters. Those would be in `expr.Parameters`. If you need to re-use the body of the lambda, you'll need to recreate it.

Alternatively, you can pass the lambda in its entirety, then call use an `InvokeExpression` to invoke the lambda.

EDIT: To answer your question, you must pass the parameters along with the body of the expression. The parameter used must be reference equivalent to what's in `expr.Parameters`. You can't substitute it for a newly created `ParameterExpression`.

Comment: the error I am getting is that the variable **x** is out of scope.  Which is weird the Func defines the type (Respondent).  I don't know how to add the parameter (variable definition) before passing the body of the lambda back into the code that resolves the rest of the expression tree.

Comment: Edit to answer question. Short answer is you don't add the parameter. You use the one that is there when created.